# Can we use make up in the sense of combine that way?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

My question is about British English.

I've found the following [meaning](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/make-up_1#make-up_1__3) of make up. Can we use it when we talk about mixing two substance like

> If you mix sugar and water, the water will be sugary.

Can we say

> If you make up sugar and water, the water will be sugary.

Comment: How is it about British English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot.

The definition says that 'make up' is used *to combine together to form something larger.* The example follows *"Women make up 40 per cent of the workforce."*

You are probably confused with the text in *gray* which says *To mix thing* **but** it is under the title of *Synonyms and related words*.

---

Suggestion: Try to refer more than one dictionary even though the meaning from the first dictionary you refer is clear to you.

Comment: What dictionary would you suggest using as the most helpful from your opinion?

Comment: A few that I refer generally: [Oxford](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/), [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/), [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/), and [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/). Bookmark them all.

Comment: @MaulikV Do you consider "Water and sugar makes up a sugary solution" incorrect?